# IDA PRO + Windows 10 + WinDbg

Tags: ida, debugging, windbg

I didn't know That we've got a Reverse Engineering community around here :D
I am very glad on that....

anyway...
I haven't used IDA Pro for quite some time, upgraded to win 10 in the mean time.

I am unable to launch debugging directly from IDA Pro. WinDbg is setup correctly, windbg attaches a process just fine on itself. WinDbg has been added to the PATH variable.

When i try to launch debugging from ida PRO,or attach I get the error:

"Could not initialize WinDgbEngine (..) %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

ideas? seems like something is wrong with parameters passing?

Comment: I've spent a couple of hours on this one..making me sick..anyone?

Comment: I have even tried to use remote debugging for a local app and its unable to cope with WInDbg..

Comment: I've even downloaded another verion of windbg..older one.. is it a known issue?

Comment: Sounds like a similar *issue* I had when opening .dmp files with WinDbg. I don't remember the exact details but opening .dmp files directly with WinDbg required setting up the shell extension registry key somewhat differently. Can you open a .dmp file by double clicking it? If not, you could research that and that might also solve your issue.

Comment: Please be specific. Do you mean WinDbg or WinDbgX (aka WinDbg Preview)?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I've found a solution please note that you need to couple your IDA with an appropriate version of *x86* windbg... latest release of WinDbg wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to solve that problem in WinDbg, I just have to run the Debugger as Administrator, and the (%1 is not a win32 application) message goes away when I use Open dump file with WinDbg.  It only happens if you try to double click a dump file without having the correct permissions. I know it's pretty basic, but always run IDA Pro or WinDBG as administrator and that message should not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I  solved this problem by configure the window PATH environment variable to point to the WinDbg64 for and not the x86 version.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the latest release of WinDbg but while debugging a 32-bit EXE, adding the WinDbgx64 directory to the PATH environment solved this problem.

Works as well with remote Windbg.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the latest release of WinDbg but while debugging a 32-bit EXE, adding the WinDbgx64 directory to the PATH environment solved this problem.

I solved this problem by configure the window PATH environment variable to point to the WinDbg64 for and not the x86 version.

Thanks This Two Answer is helpful for me