# Can't debug process with IDA Windbg debugger: "Could not initialize WinDbg engine with error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: ida, c++, debuggers, windbg

I tried to debug a C++ that I created but I am getting the following error:
[image]

I have this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64` in the `PATH` environment variable (based on [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13526/ida-pro-windows-10-windbg)), but I still have the above error.

Any idea what be the reason?
My WinDBG is not the latest but pretty updated.

Answer (score 2):

maybe try : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\**x86**